# How to resolve the page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class LoginChecker
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $id_user=session('id_user');

        if ($id_user==null){
            return redirect('/');
        }else{
            return redirect('/myaccount');
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

You need to go

`app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php:29`

and change this

`protected  $redirectTo = '/home';`

variable to where you want to be redirected.